# How to configure Knex for Bookshelf with Kraken.js

Tags: node.js, bookshelf.js, knex.js, kraken.js

I am trying to integrate Knex (which I used on a previous app that did not use kraken.js), but I need it now for my ORM (bookshelf.js).  I came across [this post](https://github.com/krakenjs/kraken-js/issues/408) while researching, but I'm still a little fuzzy.  This is for a mysql DB.

Where should I create the connection so I can pass it to the bookshelf object for my models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set it as a global object in your `onconfig()` handler.  Something like this:

**config.json**:

```
//...
"databaseConfig": {
  "host": // db host
  "database": // db name
  "user": //db user
  "password": //db pass
},
```

**lib/bs.js**

```
var bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(global.db);
module.exports = function Bookshelf() {
  return bookshelf;
};
```

**index.js**:

```
var options = {
  onconfig: function(config, next) {
    global.db = require('knex')({
      client: 'mysql',
      connection: config.get('databaseConfig')
    });

    next(null, config);
  }
};
```

When you need your bookshelf object to define your models, you can include it and it's ready to go:

**models/accounts.js**

```
   var bs = require('../lib/bs')();

    var Account = bs.Model.extend({
      idAttribute: 'id',
      tableName: 'accounts'
    });

    module.exports = function AccountModel() {
      return Account;
    }
```

There's other ways to do it, but this is clean and should suffice for what you need.